# How to setup Typo3 so client-side caching is enabled?

Tags: caching, client-side, typo3, browser-cache

I have found the following page on the matter: http://typo3.org/development/articles/using-cache-control-headers-in-typo3/page/3/

But enabling `config.sendCacheHeaders` does not seem to give me what I want..

There are no plugins/USER_INT's on the page, or COA_INT's..

These are my settings, am I missing something?

```
config {
    no_cache = 0
    sendCacheHeaders = 1
    cache_period = 86400
    cache_clearAtMidnight = 1
}
```

And this is what I get:

```
Cache-Control:private
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 09 Oct 2011 09:54:34 GMT
Expires:0
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=96
Last-Modified:Sun, 09 Oct 2011 09:54:35 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
Set-Cookie:fe_typo_user=dae661509c578eeb1eca789a45399be2; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.1
```

I'm using Typo3 4.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgot to check back here. The problem is solved, I think the cache didn't work because I was still logged into the Typo3 backend. Logging out of Typo3 solved this. Doh!

Comment: yes, a backend login disables the cache. Checking headers with `curl -I` is helpful here.